# Toolbar and ActionBar not shown in activity

Tags: android

I use Material design firstly in my apps and my problem is when I create activity there is no action bar or toolbar but I have Material Navigation drawer why it not implemented automatically like in older versions
Layout of activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:
     package fragments;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;


  public class Noname1 extends ActionBarActivity{

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.test);

   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

}
`
My theme:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/nliveo_green_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/nliveo_green_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/nliveo_green_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myTextPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/myWindowBackground</item>
</style>
```

Comment: check this https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: @Raghunandan it means I should add it manually but when I have added it neither home button not shown nor title

Comment: yes you need to. You can customize the toolbar. also you can set toolbar to act as actionbar with `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`. Further check the google io sched app 2014

Comment: what is `minSdkVersion` of your project? Is it <11?

Comment: @Apurva  have no minSdkVersion should I?

Comment: Check your `build.gradle` file, if your `minSdkVersion` is <11 then you dont need to import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`, import `android.app.Activity;` instead

Comment: @Apurva if you are targeting below 11 its hardly 10% https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: @Apurva  thank you  for information do you know actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) in toolbat

Comment: actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) works for actionBar but may not work for toolBar

Comment: @Apurva  how I can navigate back then?

Comment: @Sultan `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` then `ActionBar bar =getSupportActionBar()`. then the rest

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` if you are using support library and if not then remove `Support`

Comment: I just wrote my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a custom_toolbar.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/nliveo_green_colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Include it in your layout file wherever you want like:

```
<include android:id="@+id/toolBar" layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>
```

in Your onCreate Method:

```
public class Noname1 extends ActionBarActivity{

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.test);
     Toolbar tb = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
     setSupportActionBar(tb);
   }
}
```

And keep your manifest file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/nliveo_green_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/nliveo_green_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/nliveo_green_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myTextPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/myWindowBackground</item>
</style>
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: how  to set    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) in toolbar I cant

Comment: Depedending on your desired API levels, try to  **extend AppCompatActivity**, as it provides a ToolBar automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You should include toolbar in your layout. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 2):

Write `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` if you are using support library and if not then remove `Support` just write `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`