# activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar) not showing toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

This is my code:

```
     binding= DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_reservation_details,container,false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)binding.toolbarReservationDetails;
    toolbar.setTitle("Rezervacija");
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

In my manifest I have thi style set to activity:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

which has this style:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Are you actually adding it to the on-screen `View` hierarchy anywhere? That code shows that you've just inflated it, but not that you've added it.

Comment: i solve my same issue from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545804/toolbar-and-actionbar-not-shown-in-activity][1] may also help you @Vlado

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think that you're setting content before adding toolbar,
instead use

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

after adding toolbar.

Hope that hepls

Comment: Problem is with styling. I set some styles but above the toolbar area is white (place where should be icons, batery status etc.)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You need to setContentView in order to get the toolbar from the layout.